# Fullscreen api being closed on file input - chrome android

Tags: javascript, android, google-chrome, file-upload, fullscreen

I'm using the javascript fullscreen api in chrome on an android phone. This works fine. But whilst in fullscreen I have a input type file that will allow the user to select a file which will then be displayed using the file reader api.

My problem is that when the file input is clicked, and then an input method is chosen e.g. camera/gallery, this stops fullscreen mode.

I have tried re-initializing fullscreen on the click for the file input but because the fullscreen is stopped only when a file upload option is chosen (relying on the android os) I have found no way of knowing when that is.

I can get around this by setting a timeout, but if the user takes a while to select an upload method potentially the timeout can occur too early.

I have tried going to fullscreen mode on `fullscreenchange` event but fullscreen requires a click, so this isn't working.

Is there any way to avoid this issue, or what would be the best method to get around it?

Comment: You're right. For now, i just set a click event for `window` when file-selector is open, and show an overlay message ("tap and continue") to enter fullscreen again.